# Decompressing Linux zImage

Tags: linux-kernel, reverse-engineering, compression, disassembly, firmware

I'm trying to decompress a zImage. I have a firmware binary I dumped from a flash chip. Analyzing it with binwalk gives the following:

```
$ binwalk flash_dump.bin

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
352832        0x56240         Linux kernel ARM boot executable zImage (big-endian)
10617408      0xA20240        Linux kernel ARM boot executable zImage (big-endian)
10630468      0xA23544        device tree image (dtb)
```

I tried to separate the first Linux zImage:

```
$ dd if=flash_dump.bin of=zImage bs=1 skip=352832 count=10264576

10264576+0 records in
10264576+0 records out
10264576 bytes (10 MB, 9.8 MiB) copied, 13.7267 s, 748 kB/s
```

Making sure it's still a zImage:

```
$ file zImage

zImage: Linux kernel ARM boot executable zImage (big-endian)
```

Searching for the gZip header:

```
$ arm-none-eabi-objdump -EB -b binary -D -m armv5t zImage | grep 8b1f

15e4c:  b81c8b1f    ldmdalt ip, {r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, r8, r9, fp, pc}
401f8:  0b3d2bfe    bleq    0xf8b1f8
```

I can't seem to find the gZip header.

How can I decompress the zImage? I would like to look at it through a disassembler like IDA Pro.

Comment: How do you know you didn't find it?

Comment: Will this help? - http://bootloader.wikidot.com/linux:boot:zimage-layout

Answer (score 1):

The zImage is big-endian (see binwalk result). You should grep for `1f8b` instead.

Answer (score 0):

(cant comment)

@Gao Yuan is *not* correct in *this* specific case, as its a *header byte tag* (otherwise known as a MAGIC) made up of 2 individual (8bit) bytes that is being looked for (as opposed to a 16bit value), the 1st is `1f` the 2nd is `8b`, and usually followed by `08` (the compression method).

IE. because it is a MAGIC it is *not* byte-swapped when written / created. It has to be recognisable across *any endian* platform, otherwise it defeats the purpose of being a MAGIC

I just tested this on a RPi:

`xxd /boot/kernel.img  | grep '1f8b 08'` (offset 0x4730 - kernel zImage)

`xxd /boot/kernel8.img | grep '1f8b 08'` (offset 0 - standard .gz)

And a Linux-m68k kernel for the Tadpole VME SBC:

`xxd vmlinux.gz        | grep '1f8b 08'` (offset 0 - standard .gz)

---

OP: the next byte you found after `1f8b` was `0b` which I would say is the *compression method byte* (just not a standard one). But something is fishy, as 15K HEX into a zImage is a bit excessive (the RPi zImage kernels are about 4-5K HEX) , but if thats the only value, then that is indead the Gzip header.